# Prevent removal of bootstrapper

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a custom bootstrapper that allows the user to uninstall components of the installation or the entire installation. In either situation, the bootstrapper is removed and no longer available in 'Programs and Features'. Is there a way I can prevent the bundle from being removed if I know the user is just uninstalling a component of the installation?

I thought maybe I could set the installation state to modify but I don't see a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the **Plan** phase, you need to handle a handful of events to set the `State` you want for each MsiFeature and Package within your bundle.

For each wix `msifeature` and/or `package` the user is *changing*, you'll need to set the `State` value of the event args to `AddLocal` or `Remove` for features, and `Present` or `Absent` for packages during the planning phase event handlers (`BootstrapperApplication.PlanPackageBegin` and `BootstrapperApplication.PlanMsiFeature`). For any remaining *unchanged*, set the state to `None`.

Then, when you call `Engine.Plan(...)`, you'll need to provide a LaunchAction value of `Modify` or `Install` if you want the bootstrapper to exist after the run, or `Uninstall` if you want to have the bootstrapper removed.  **I suspect this is where you're having issues -- check what value you're passing to `Plan()`**

I wrote a series of blog posts you may find helpful (particularly part 5): [Writing Your Own .NET-based Installer with WiX](https://www.wrightfully.com/series/writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix)